# Get whole node by post type

Tags: 8, entities

Is there any way of getting a node by its post type? I've tried with the following code, but it doesn't really work.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('front_page_slider');
```

As far as I read on tutorials, it should work when the content type is *front_page_slider*. Instead, it returns an error.

> The "front_page_slider" entity type does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you call *post type* is for Drupal a *content type*, or an *entity bundle*. The first argument of `\Drupal::entityQuery()` is the entity type that, in the case of nodes, is *node*.

The code you need is the following one.

```
use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'front_page_slider')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->execute();

$nodes = Node::loadMultiple($nids);
```

Note I added the `condition('status', 1)` line, which returns only the published nodes; if you are not interested only in the published nodes, you can leave that line off.

Furthermore, if you are executing the code without showing the result to the currently logged-in user, for example because it runs at cron time, you should disable the access check, and use the following code.

```
// Put the following line at the beginning of the file containing the code.
use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'front_page_slider')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->accessCheck(FALSE)
  ->execute();

$nodes = Node::loadMultiple($nids);
```

Differently, you would get only the nodes for which the currently logged-in user has access.
In the example of a `hook_cron()` implementation, that user is the anonymous user. Without the `accessCheck(FALSE)` line, the code would get only the published nodes to which anonymous users have access, which could be none, if the user permissions don't allow anonymous users to see nodes.

`accessCheck(FALSE)` is used by [`node_access_rebuild()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_access_rebuild/8.2.x), which contains the following lines. (Read the comment before the code.)

```
  // Disable access checking since all nodes must be processed even if the
  // user does not have access. And unless the current user has the bypass
  // node access permission, no nodes are accessible since the grants have
  // just been deleted.
  $entity_query->accessCheck(FALSE);
```